# Field Calculate unique ID, based on another column, overriding FID / Object ID order

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a couple thousand polygons across several hundred towns.  I want the polygons within each town be labelled as such - first 3 letters of town name + _ + incrementing ID, so that they might look like this:

```
Ale_01
Ale_02
Bur_01
Bur_02
```

And so on.

Using the Python Parser of the Field Calculator, I have tried using an augmented version of the standard ID incrementing script floating around (pasted below):

```
prev_town = "" 
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(%Town%): 
 global rec
 global prev_town
 if town != prev_town:
  rec = 0 
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
 id = town[0:3] + "_" + str(rec).zfill(2)
 return id
```

The problem is that, the records within and across towns, were added at different times (i.e. Bur_01 was added before Ale_02), so that even after sorting by town, when applying the above script, I can get repeat ID (Ale_01 twice) due to the fact that the field calculator is applied in the order of ObjectID, and it doesn't (of course) keep track of previous IDs.

So, I have tried to augment the above code like so:

```
prev_town = ""
rec=0 
ids = []
id = ""
def autoIncrement(town): 
 global prev_town
 global rec
 global ids
 global id
 if town != prev_town:
  rec = 0
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval
 id = town[0:3] + "_" + str(rec).zfill(2)
 while( id in ids):
  if town != prev_town:
   rec = 0
  pStart = 1  
  pInterval = 1 
  if (rec == 0):  
   rec = pStart  
  else:  
   rec += pInterval
  id = town[0:3] + "_" + str(rec).zfill(2)
 ids.append(id)
 return id
```

But, this seems to hang and never complete - so I can't even tell if it is working or not....

Also, this data layer is a feature service, so I am trying to do this on a local replica and sync back - that of course brings with it its own limitations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the "standard ID incrementing script" that you mention being implemented using the Python Parser of the ArcGIS Field Calculator, or in some other way?  I suspect it would be easier to use an update cursor.

Comment: The Python Parser of the Field Calculator.